# Controlling visual stacking order of images and colour bars in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, graphics, colorbar

How do I control the visual stacking order of images and colour bars in Matlab?
 I have 6 images that I show on a 2 x 3 grid using subplot. I add colour bars to each of the images, but some of the colour bars appear behind the images, rendering them invisible. In my example, colour bars belonging to image 3 and 5 (counting as in the subplot command) appear behind their respective images.

I do not think I will be able to use the order of axes children objects, as each axes apparently only has one child, i.e. the image, and the colour bar object is child of the figure (Must be the same as its associated axes).

I have also tried uistack (with top for colour bars, and bottom for images), and although it does change appearances, in the end, other colour bars will wind up behind the images. It seems random which ones, for example after uistack on the image and colour bar belonging to subplot 5, the colour bar of subplot 2 will suddenly appear behind its image.

PS I also tried reordering the children of the figure, but they do not change (even with painters render)

Comment: Make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. If you have code that doesn't work you need to add it to your question along with a screen shot of the resulting figures...

Comment: Do you draw your color bars with `patch`? Actually, can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very strange: When I just prepared the MCVE, the problem did not reproduce, but I have no idea what is different! Maybe a Windows update? Anyway, the original output with the problem is shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJVG2.png, and the prepared example output which looks as it should here https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1LMX.png. So for now, there is no problem...

The code is

```
function example()
I1=ones(96,96);
I2=ones(96,96)+1;
I3=ones(96,96)+2;
I4=ones(96,96)+3;
I5=ones(96,96)+4;
I6=ones(96,96)+5;


pos=[10 10 12 9];

fig=figure
fig.Units='centimeters';
fig.Position=pos;
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto');

   h(1)=veryTightSubPlot(2,3,1); 
   imshow(I1,[0,6]);
   h(2)=veryTightSubPlot(2,3,2);
   imshow(I2,[0,6]);
   h(3)=veryTightSubPlot(2,3,3);
   imshow(I3,[0,6]);

   h(4)=veryTightSubPlot(2,3,4); 
   imshow(I4,[0,6]);
   h(5)=veryTightSubPlot(2,3,5);
   imshow(I5,[0,6]);
   h(6)=veryTightSubPlot(2,3,6);
   imshow(I6,[0,6]);

V=[0.315,0.65,0.97,0.315,0.65,0.97,0.315,0.65,0.97];
for i=1:6
    p=get(h(i),'Position');
    c=colorbar(h(i),'Axislocation','in','FontSize',8);
    c.Color=[0,0,0];
    cp=c.Position;

    h(i).Position=p;
    cp(3)=cp(3)/2;
    c.Position=[V(i) cp(2:4)];
end
colormap(parula);
end

function [ax] = veryTightSubPlot(rows, columns,index)
    ix = mod(index-1,columns);
    iy = floor((index-1)/columns);
    pos = [ix/columns,1-(iy+1)/rows,1/columns,1/rows];
    ax = axes('ActivePositionProperty','outerposition','Position',pos);
end
```